# SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface then SDL_UpdateTexture messes colors

Tags: c++, colors, sdl

I load a png file to a surface and create a texture from it

later I modify the surface then use SDL_UpdateTexture

problem:

**SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface respects the color format** from surface to texture

**while SDL_UpdateTexture does not (red and blue colors are swapped)**

```
SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, (Uint8*)surface->pixels, surface->w * sizeof(Uint32));
```

here is the code that loads the file, nothing fancy

```
void MyClass::loadFromFile( std::string path)
{
    surface = IMG_Load( path.c_str() );
    
    //SDL_SetColorKey( surface, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB( surface->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( core->getRenderer(), surface );
}
```

I tried :

- commenting SDL_SetColorKey
- commenting the code that modifies the surface pixels ( just calling SDL_UpdateTexture )

this really looks like a SDL bug since I cannot pass any format to SDL_UpdateTexture

am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

SDL_UpdateTexture is proably buggy, so I just copy pixels

```
gStreamingTexture.lockTexture();
gStreamingTexture.copyPixels( gDataStream.getBuffer() );
gStreamingTexture.unlockTexture();
```

copyPixels just does this

```
memcpy( mPixels, pixels, mPitch * mHeight );
```

details : https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/42_texture_streaming/index.php